# Passing `null` reference for a `ref struct` parameter in interop method

Tags: c#, null, interop, parameter-passing, value-type

I am using C# to call a DLL function.

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetValue(
        pHandle handle,
        ref somestruct a,
        ref somestruct b);
```

How can I pass a `null` reference for argument 3?

When I try, I am getting a compile-time error:

> *Cannot convert from `<null>` to ref somestruct.*

I also tried `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: It is a `ref` parameter? So why don't you show us the exact method signature? Is `somestruct` really a struct or a class?

Comment: fixed it.It's a struct

Comment: Can this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Make `somestruct` a class, and change the function signature to:

   ```
   [DllImport("MyDLL.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern uint GetValue(
       pHandle handle, somestruct a, somestruct b);
   ```

   Usually this must not change anything else, except that you can pass a `null` as the value of `a` and `b`.
2. Add another overload for the function, like this:

   ```
   [DllImport("MyDLL.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern uint GetValue(
       pHandle handle, IntPtr a, IntPtr b);
   ```

   Now you can call the function with `IntPtr.Zero`, in addition to a `ref` to an object of type `somestruct`:

   ```
   GetValue(myHandle, ref myStruct1, ref myStruct2);
   GetValue(myHandle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
   ```

Comment: This is not very commonly known technique, very useful!

Answer (score 3):

Since .NET 5.0 there is [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.NullRef<T>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.nullref?view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_CompilerServices_Unsafe_NullRef__1)

```
GetValue(myHandle, ref myStruct1, ref myStruct2);
GetValue(myHandle, ref Unsafe.NullRef<somestruct>(), ref Unsafe.NullRef<somestruct>());
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15217647/240733) suggests to make `SomeStruct` a class. I would like to show an implementation of that idea which appears to work nicely… even when you cannot change the definition of `SomeStruct` (such as when it is a predefined type like `System.Guid`; see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910988/240733)).

1. Define a generic wrapper class:

   ```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
   public sealed class SomeStructRef
   {
       [FieldOffset(0)]
       private SomeStruct value;

       public static implicit operator SomeStructRef(SomeStruct value)
       {
           return new SomeStructRef { value = value };
       }
   }
   ```

   The basic idea here is identical to [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).
2. Change your interop method definition to the following:

   ```
   [DllImport("MyDLL.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern uint GetValue(
       pHandle handle,
       ref SomeStruct a,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] SomeStructRef b);
   ```

The third parameter `b` will then be "nullable". Since `SomeStructRef` is a reference type, you can pass a `null` reference. You can also pass a `SomeStruct` value because an implicit conversion operator from `SomeStruct` to `SomeStructRef` exists. And (at least in theory), due to the `[StructLayout]`/`[FieldOffset]` marshalling instructions, any instance of `SomeStructRef` should get marshalled just like an actual instance of `SomeStruct`.

I'd be happy if someone who is an interop expert could validate the soundness of this techinque.

Answer (score 0):

Another obvious solution is to resort to `unsafe` code and change the interop method declaration to this:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", SetLastError = true)]
unsafe public static extern uint GetValue(
        pHandle handle,
        ref somestruct a,
        somestruct* b);
```

Notice that the method is now marked `unsafe`, and that the parameter has changed from `ref somestruct` to `somestruct*`.

This has the following implications:

- The method can only be called from inside an `unsafe` context. For example:

  ```
  somestruct s;
  unsafe { GetValue(…, …, &s);   }  // pass a struct `s`
  unsafe { GetValue(…, …, null); }  // pass null reference
  ```
- In order for the above to work, `unsafe` code must be allowed for the project (either in the project settings, or via the `/unsafe` command-line compiler switch).
- Using `unsafe` leads to unverifiable IL code. IIRC, this means that loading this assembly will require full trust (which can be problematic in some situations).